# Why can't I select some elements in Amazon pages using scrapy?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, selector

I'm trying to parse Amazon Standard Identification Number (ASIN) from the following page.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075GYWPCJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075GYWPCJ)

However, I cannot select the table which includes ASIN from the `scrapy` response. How can I select the table so that I can parse the data in the table?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon.com'
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075GYWPCJ', self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        # This works.. :)
        print(response.xpath('//table[@id="HLCXComparisonTable"]'))
        # This doesn't work.. :(
        print(response.xpath('//table[@id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]'))

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(AmazonSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Scrapy crawls static pages, dynamic web pages that have a lot of ajax queries running at the load time do not work very well.

Comment: As noted by others, you're dealing with dynamic pages, so you would probably need to start looking into *selenium* to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon lots of things load dynamically. The table that you're trying to grab doesn't load to the DOM when you open the page. You'll need to somehow trigger the page to load that content in order to grab it.